# Custom defined transporters colliding

Tags: anylogic

I've created a simple transporter (think of it like a box on wheels) and I have two separate TransporterFleets that each contain one of these simple transporter agents.  In the TransporterFleet blocks I specify a "Min distance to obstacle" = 0.5 meters; however when the simulation runs, the two separate transporters go right over each other from time-to-time.

Note that I have two separate TransporterFleet blocks because each transporter has certain paths that it cannot take.

What can I modify/add so that these transporters will never collide?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and suggestion from AL support was to increase transporters deceleration. If you have default value (1 m/s2) than it could be possible that transportesr cant break fast enough...

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tested it and unfortunately it doesn't help for my situation.  Appreciate any further thoughts you may have